# Why is it asking for a log-in?

Tags: force

i want to implement payment in salesforce billing and the requirement is that user Without logging into Salesforce make payments on their invoice. I implemented the following solution from the ["Help Article"](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.blng_forcecom_setup.htm&type=5) provided by the salesforce. The whole point of this method is that user wont be logging into. salesforce.com or Force.com to make payment but after clicking "Pay now" button i am getting this error.
[image]

Comment: I presume that there is a guest site user behind that. From my force.com site knowledge that either means something has been published, the site user is missing a permission or the page is throwing an error.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to set Site guest user permissions for the VF page and any objects you are accessing.  See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_public_access_settings.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic error that can be caused by a wide range of problems, including, but not limited to:

- Insufficient access to a record
- Insufficient access to an object
- Insufficient access to a field
- Insufficient access to a Visualforce page
- Insufficient access to an Apex controller
- Missing a required license
- Misconfigured URL (e.g. needs a namespace, but not provided)
- Guest User is disabled
- An uncaught exception was thrown (e.g. because of a NullPointerException)

Most likely, you skipped or incorrectly completed Step 1 or Step 3 in the Help article you linked to. You must ensure that the user has all the appropriate field, object, and class permissions, a license, if necessary, etc.

You can check out [Set Up Debug Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5) for information on how to debug Guest Users, which may provide further insight.